# Comparing results from Poisson regressions

Tags: count, statistics, regression, glm, poisson

I have a dataset with count data (y variable), one primary variable of interest (factor denoted x_1), and several variables I wish to control for (factor and numeric denoted x_i).

Say, y is the number of seats taken in a stadium. And let's say that this stadium has three levels of seating - low price (many), medium price (fewer), and high price (fewest).

A similar paper to the one I'm writing has run 4 separate Poisson regressions on the same set of x variables with y as #all seats, #low priced seats, #medium priced seats, #high priced seats respectively, and is comparing the coefficient of x_1, in each model, to test its effect on the number of low, medium, and high priced seats taken. (The total number of seats equals the sum of low, medium, and high.)

I'm wondering is there two possible problems with this?

1. The regressions all use the raw count of seats and not the count divided by the number of seats in each section. Is this wrong?
2. Is it reasonable to use 4 separate regressions in this way, or is there a more legitimate method?

As this is a theory question I think (hope) it's ok not to provide data.

Edit: Just to explain a little more, say the exponentiated coefficient for x_1 is 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, and 0.9 in the #all seats, #low priced seats, #medium priced seats, and #high priced seat regressions respectively. This is interpreted as suggesting that x_1 has the greatest effect on medium-priced seats.